# How to redirect to a specific URL in Orchard CMS if browsing from a mobile device

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

we have a Orchard site with a custom Module which has its separate _Layout/views (not rendering through Orchard's layout/theme).

we have two home pages: #1. www.xyz.com and #2. www.xyz.com/m. Where First one is the main site and the second one is the mobile site.

We want to redirect any traffic browsing the the main site (#1 url) to the mobile site (#2 url) if browsing from a mobile device or a tablet.

Where exactly in Orchard we have to make the changes to get the desired result?